# I only want to see actual x values to show on horizontal axis of Excel Chart (with scale matching those values) not let Excel do scaling and labeling

Tags: excel, charts

Below is an Excel Chart for the data shown in **column A** (x-coordinates--**dates**) and **column B** (y-coordinates--**test results**). There's no problem with the column B data. But note that the horizontal axis shows quite a few more dates than are contained in column A.

*Is there any way to have only the actual x-coordinates shown on the horizontal axis with a scale that matches those values?*

I kind of get it. Excel deliberately scales the horizontal axis to match as best it can the data in column A. But I don't want that. Beneath each "corner" point of the graph, I'd like to see the date that is associated with the test result in column B.

In other words, there is clearly a point with y-coordinate **154.5**. I'd like to see **2/13/2018** directly below that point since that is the data in row 5. Note that the x-axis contains the "correct" date for the **first** plotted point: **(2/9/2017, 70)**. But for the point with y-coordinate **80**, it looks as if that test result occurred on *6/9/2017* rather than **6/16/2018**.

So I'd like the graph to appear as shown in the second image, which likely would be impossible because of the "crowding" of x-coordinate values at the right-hand end, but just displaying whichever of the three dates would fit would be good enough,  as would just showing one of the two dates in other "crowded" areas. That is to say that something like the third image would be fine.

I suppose I could write VBA code to make it happen, but I'd prefer that Excel do it.

(*What crosses my mind is, "Are exact dates really this important?" And the jury is still out on this point. There are arguments both ways. I guess a hung jury goes to the judge, Excel*.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nothing built-in will do that. You'd have to either create dummy rows to fill in all your missing dates, then use a category axis, or use a dummy data series (XY scatter with the dates as X values and 0 as Y values) and then use data labels of that series to create your axis labels.

Comment: Au contraire. See my Answer.

Comment: With respect, the chart in your answer bears no relation to what you *said* you wanted. If you just wanted to treat the dates as categories, there's a simple axis option for that. ;)

Comment: Well, my point was clearly that I wanted to be able to read and get accurate info from the graph, and Excel was no help in this regard, having no builtin option to do so. Having used and lived with my solution for a week, I'm disappointed to realize that the dates on the category axis do not show "elapsed time" between tests at all. I was so happy to get a semblance of what I wanted that I overlooked this fairly important detail ... So what is the simple axis option to treat the dates as categories and have them associated with the test results on that date, meaning using major axis gridlines.

Comment: P.S. I'm an old hand at Excel VBA. But this was only my 2nd effort in graphing. I stumbled onto `Set s = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection` and found out that I needed to store categories (`XValues`) and `Values` into the first series in `s`. I stumbled onto the 45 degree tilt of `XValues` and found the option to make that tilt angle 45 or -45 or 60 degrees, etc. In fairness to myself, the stumbling was due to not being able to find a decent tutorial for advanced charting, as well as my not at all being an Excel expert. Lots of holes in knowledge and application of low-level concepts, I found out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inserting the points to be plotted into two arrays, `datesArr` and `scaledArr`, and putting those values into columns A and B (see worksheet) and in code saying ...

```
Set ch = ActiveChart 

Set s = ch.SeriesCollection

s(1).Values = scaledArray
s(1).XValues = datesArr
```

... I got exactly what I wanted. Now granted that's not exactly built-in, but we're programmers, yes? And this was downright easy. Well, once I learned a few tricks, especially being able to set angle of dates to 45 degrees.

[image]

Comment: This just evenly spaces the points, despite any irregularity in the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to plot two sets of data, the actual values, and a set of zeros, then smoke and mirrors make it work.

Data below left, make a line chart (top left chart). Add data labels to the second series; I colored the labels orange to match the points, for clarity in this description. Default labels show Y values, which are all zero (top right). Format the data labels to show category values (i.e., dates), below the points, rotated upwards (bottom left). Format format format (bottom right). Axis labels: none. Format second series with medium gray lines and medium gray cross markers. Drag bottom of plot area upwards to make room for the date labels. Hide legend.

[image: Show only specific dates along axis]